# How can I set the range of salary for the employee table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there way that we can set range of values for salary column of employee table. It's required that there can insert salary value between `10000-70000` only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community of volunteers offering aid to programmers stuck on a 
particular task. We are not a service to write free code for you. Please read 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (What topics can I ask about here?) and 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (How do I ask a good question?)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your table constraint while creating table.

```
CONSTRAINT Salary_Ck CHECK (Salary >= 10000 AND Salary <= 70000)
```

Comment: Yep good approach. check at database layer makes it near impossible to bypass this check unless someone disables it first!

Comment: yes it's not working for both mysql and innodb. please let me know that how can check database layer and make it

Comment: Try the new syntax.